# bash: Saving aliases beyond one session

Tags: bash, alias, session

Recently, I've been fiddling around with Linux's terminal commands to try and get a better feel for the system.

I was happy to know that I could give commands a different name in order to call them, using the alias command. For example,

```
alias print="echo"
```

In this case, the `echo` would be replaced by `print`.

The only problem is that it only seems to stay for one terminal session. Without the use of third party software, is there a way that I can keep these aliases permanently? If there are software alternatives, I'll be glad to hear them.

I'm just looking for a way to do this without downloading anything.

Comment: Sure, just save those `alias`es in your shell's `rc` file. (For `bash`, this is `~/.bashrc`; for `zsh`, this is `~/.zshrc`; for other shells it will be elsewhere)

Answer (score 5):

You need to put your aliases in a file that will be read upon start of all sessions.

Your `~/.bashrc` file should have the following:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

that means if you have a file `~/.bash_aliases` file then it will be sourced and all the aliases defined in it will be applied in the session. It is the best practice to save your aliases in `~/.bash_aliases`, if you don't have the file you can create it manually. As an alternative you can put your aliases in `~/.bashrc`.

Also note that, if you want to permanently save the aliases those are defined only for current session of terminal, you can run:

```
alias >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `.bashalias` in your home directory, or edit the existing file `~/.bashalias`. To have this file read every time you start a bash session, add the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

`source ~/.bashalias`

Comment: Really? What `Bash` version do you have?

Comment: `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)`

So, admittedly, OS X not Mint, but I would be surprised to learn that the Bash included on Mint doesn't allow .bashalias....

Comment: Is sourcing `.bashalias` added to any of your Bash startup files explicitly?

Comment: oh, whoops, you're right. my bad!

Answer (score 1):

The common way is to set your aliases in the `.bashrc` file of your home directory (if you use `bash` as your shell of course).

`.bashrc` is file read by `bash` anytime you launch a terminal.

Just edit it (watch out, files with a name starting by a `.` are hidden by default) and add a line like:

```
alias ll='ls -l'
```

If you want to test it without launching a new terminal, just `source` it:

```
$ ll
bash: ll: command not found

$ source ~/.bashrc

$ ll
-rw-rw-r--  1 apaul apaul  31 Mar  7 21:51 file1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous comments if someone is using `zsh` the way that you can add aliases is using the `.zshrc` file using the command below:

```
sudo nano ~/.zshrc
```

*Note that the `sudo` is not necessary and you can use `vim` also or other editor choice, by the way, for a GUI `gedit` is also a great option if your computer use that text editor.*

Then you have to add at the end of the file the aliases:

```
alias print="echo"
```

I'm not sure why on my case changing the `.bashrc` file doesn't work, probably that behaviour is produced by the change of the default terminal.